# Add email Signup Form when the video ends

Tags: javascript, html, video, html5-video

I am trying to call an email sign up form when the video ends. My problem I don't know how to call the form inside the javascript, so far what I have achieved is to call an alert when the video ends.
Can someone please help me with this?

```
<video id="myVideo" controls="controls" width="300" height="150">
    <source src="http://movie.webm" type="video/webm" />
    <source src="your_video_file.ogg" type="video/ogg" />
    Your browser does not support HTML5 video.
</video>

<script type="text/javascript">
    document.getElementById('myVideo').addEventListener('ended', myHandler, false);
    function myHandler(e) {
        if (!e) { e = window.event; }
        alert("Video Finished");
    }
</script>
```

/*** UPDATE - FOR SOMEONE WHO ARE LOOKING FOR THE SAME HERE IS THE CODE ********/

```
        <!DOCTYPE html>
       <html>

       <head>      
       <style>

       #overlayContactForm {
       visibility: hidden;
       position: absolute;
       left: 0px;
       top: 0px;
       width:100%;
       height:100%;
       text-align:center;
       z-index: 1000;
       }    
       #overlayContactForm div {
       width: 428px;
       margin: 65px;
       background-color: #fff;
       border: 1px solid #000;
       padding: 15px;
       text-align: center;
       height: 200px;  
      }
      </style> 
      </head>
      <body>
      <div id="player"></div>
      <script src="http://www.youtube.com/player_api"></script>
     <div align="center">
    <script>

    // create youtube player
    var player;
    function onYouTubePlayerAPIReady() {
    player = new YT.Player('player', {
      height: '390',
      width: '640',
      videoId: 'VhvUEhxL1DQ',
      playerVars: {rel: 0},
      events: {
        'onReady': onPlayerReady,
        'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange
      }
    });
    }

     // autoplay video
    function onPlayerReady(event) {
    event.target.playVideo();
    }

    // when video ends
    function onPlayerStateChange(event) {        
    if(event.data === 0) {            
   el = document.getElementById("overlayContactForm");
    el.style.visibility = (el.style.visibility == "visible") ? "hidden" : 
   "visible";     
    }
    }

   </script>
  </div>
  <div id="overlayContactForm">
  <div>
  <h1> Text Header Info </h1>
  <form class="form-inline">
  <input type="email" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail3"   
  placeholder="Email Address">
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Sign in</button>
  </form>
   <p> Testing email opt-in - Video/Form </p>
   </div>
  </div>
  </body>
  </html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Handle the javascript video end event as:

```
var signupForm;                     // reference to the sign-up form
signupForm.style.display = '';      // form initially hidden

// on video end
document.getElementById('myVideo').onended = function(e) {
    signupForm.style.display = 'block';
};
```

**EDIT**:
Assuming that signupForm is a modal dialog, you can change the even handlers like this

```
var button;     // reference to the button

document.getElementById('myVideo').onended = function(e) {
    button.click();
};

button.onclick = function(e) {
    signupForm.style.display = 'block';
}
```

So the modal will now show up both when button is clicked or the video has ended.

Comment: Hi Shreevardhan I appreciate your prompt response .  I have managed to find a way. I have another task probably  you can help me out . I would like to call all my new code from button and display it into a lightbox or a modal box .

Comment: @CabLondon then use `button.click()` inside the event handler and define that button's `onclick` event handler to display the modal dialog

Comment: I am really newbie on coding, would you mind to give me an example please.

Comment: @CabLondon see the edited answer. Accept and upvote the answer if your's problem's solved